word2vec download taking too long
Windows10, IDLE, The download time is too long for the below code.
import gensim.downloader as api
word_vec_list = api.load('word2vec-google-news-300')


Is it possible that I download only fewer words?
Is it possible to download the dataset as csv and use it later in the program?


The code you're using is trying to download a large pre-trained Word2Vec model (~1.5 GB) from the Gensim library, which can indeed take a significant amount of time.
Here are a few suggestions to speed up the download process:

Check your internet connection: Ensure that your internet connection is stable and fast. A slow internet connection can significantly slow down the download process.
Use a faster mirror: Gensim uses a default mirror to download the models. You can try changing the mirror to a faster one. You can do this by setting the mirror parameter when calling the load function:

